# Why use ion-datetime instead of ion-input type="date"

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework

I was using ionic v5 and recently updated to v6.  As result my `ion-datetime` controls changed from the vertical scrolling type ui to the calendar.  I do want a calender instead of the vertical scroll, but the `ion-datetime` control in v6 does not popup the calendar on click. It is just there taking up a lot of space.  However, `ion-input type="date"` does exactly what I need.  So my question is why bother with `ion-datetime`?  Is it somehow more compatible across devices?  And is there a way to accomplish the same functionality and ui as the default behavior of `ion-input type="date"` with `ion-datetime`?

Comment: I'd say that ion-datetime gives you a lot more options to customize the functionality, look and feel, than ion-input. As for click functionality, you'd need to wrap the ion-datetime and control the displaying of the wrapper through clicks. That being said, for more dynamical approach, you can make a modal containing ion-datetime and use it across your project.

Comment: Actually is done popup a calendar on click. Please Check Documentation there is an option to show calendar as Modal. and and popover with other customisation options. https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime#interfaces and see `<!-- Datetime in overlay -->` option.

Comment: That solved my issues.  I was able to use the popover to get what I want.